# Will Dynamically created content using jquery be visible to search engines?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a small website with less than 10 pages.

The title tag contains the Site Name like so:

```
<title><?php echo SITE_NAME; ?></title>
```

I am using the following code to dynamically append the Page Title to the title tag:

```
var url = window.location.href; 
// Url format : localhost/mysite/?page=home

  if (url.indexOf('=') == -1) {
  var path = 'home';
  } else {
    var path = window.location.href.split("=").pop();
  }

var pageName = $('h2:first').text();
  if(path == 'home') {
    var pageName = 'Home';
  } else {
    var pageName = $('h2:first').text();
  }

  $("title").append(" - " + pageName);
```

Would this dynamically generated Page Title be visible to search engines?
Would the title be displayed along with the Site Name in the SERPS?

Comment: Though most SE, at least Google, renders JS, I'd still recommend against using JQuery to generate the title.
Why don't you use PHP for the same? Just check `$_GET["page"]` and change the title accordingly

Comment: The problem is that the $_GET["page"] value won't always be the same as the Page Name. For instance, if the $_GET value is "mission-vision", then the page value would be "Mission & Vision". If I use an array in Php to store the $_GET value and its corresponding Page Name value, every time a new page is created, I or some other developer will have to remember to update this array.

Comment: How are you generating the Page Name? Are they hard coded, or do they come from somewhere?

Comment: Its hard coded .

Comment: Oh..! That's too bad, because:
1. Most SEs, crawlers, etc. won't see it. Major players like Google do render JS, but it depends on how and when your title gets changed. However, at least Google, doesn't always use the title you have specified. It may alter it to _better_ suit what the user wants.
2. It'd recommend against using the method you are using. It might be more of a personal preference than a rule/standard. But what you are doing might be easy and work for now, but it can be problematic as you scale, or need flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the big player SE's can and often do render JS, they don't render everything, and don't trigger any user actions. So it depends a lot on how and when this snippet is getting called. Also, at least Google, doesn't always use the title in the source as the tile in the search results.
However, I'd strongly recommend against what you are doing. This, imho, is highly inefficient and non-scale able. Also, most crawlers will miss out on your title this way.